# Storing files on the filesystem

Tags: c#, file, hierarchy, storage

I have an application that stores images in a database.
Now I have learned that this isn't the best way to do this because of performance.

I've started extracting all the "blobs" out of the database and added them (through a virtual folder) into the data folder

the problem is that I allready have 8000 blobs stored and if I put them in the folder like this "data/< blobid >/< blobname.extension >" this folder will contain to many folder to be manageable.

I was wondering how you can store your files the best?
group them in dates of creation like this "data/< year >/< month >/< day >/< blobid >/< name >".
I also have to add that our files are stored in a tree in the database.
I was wondering if I should map that treestructure to the filesystem, the only problem there is that you can move branches. That would mean that I have to move the branches on the filesystem.

Any help is welcome.

Grtz,
M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of SQL Server are you using? Because if you are using 2008 you can use the [FILESTREAM datatype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) to store images. This is just as efficient as storing them on the filestore but without any of the associated hassle. See [Getting Traction with SQL Server 2008 Filestream](http://blogs.msdn.com/rdoherty/archive/2007/10/12/getting-traction-with-sql-server-2008-filestream.aspx).

Comment: +1 - I wasn't aware of this type but it sounds like I should be using it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple strategy is grouping according to the first [few] digit(s). E.g.:

```
1/
    2/
        123.blob
        129.blob
    5/
        151.blob
2/
    0/
        208.blob
```

That way, you know you'll never have more than 10 subdirectories in a directory. You may of course use more or less levels (of directories) and/or more digits per level.

A more complex, dynamic system could create sublevels on demand: If the number of blobs in a certain directory exceed a preset maximum, create another 10 subdirectories and move the files in.

Answer (score 1):

Most filesystems for BLOB data will set up a number of subdirectories.  For instance, if you have IDs 1-10000, you could have:

```
00/
    00/
    01/
    02/
        00020.blob
        00021.blob
        ...
    ...
01/
02/
03/
...
```

The other question I have back for you:  why is it so bad for you to manage them as BLOBs?

Comment: because our database is huge + we would like to stream our files (video, music) to our flex application.

Comment: No problems with huge DBs, are you "streaming" over HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the files in the relevant tree structure? If not you could name the file /YOURFOLDER/blobid_blobname.extension. This way the upload folder acts purely as a repository for the data rather than mimicking the data structure.